# neo4jclient: CS1501: No overload for method 'OnCreate' takes 1 arguments

Tags: neo4jclient

My objective is to Update if Exists or Create the node if it does not.

My code is as follows :

public bool  CreateEntity (String sEntityName, String sEntityType, bool bAllowDuplicates)
    {

```
    if (bAllowDuplicates)
    {
    var newEntity= new Entity {EntityName=sEntityName, EntityType=sEntityType};
        client.Cypher
            .Create("(entity:Entity {ParamnewEntity})")
            .WithParam("ParamnewEntity",newEntity)
            .ExecuteWithoutResults();
    }
    else
    {
    var newEntity = new Entity { EntityName = sEntityName, EntityType = sEntityType };
    client.Cypher
        .Merge("(entity:Entity { EntityName: {entityname} })")
        .OnCreate("entity")
        .Set("entity = {newEntity}")
            .WithParams(new {
            entityname = newEntity.EntityName,
            newEntity
            }
        )
        .ExecuteWithoutResults();

    }       



    return true;
}
```

The Class Definition : 
public class Entity
    {
        public string EntityName  { get; set;}
        public string EntityType  { get; set;}

```
}
```

This code gives an error  : 
CS1501: No overload for method 'OnCreate' takes 1 arguments

What is my mistake ?

BTW is there a place for me to look at the API doc for neo4jclient ?

Im using Neo4jClient.1.0.0.656.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like `OnCreate` accepts *any* parameters.  Try just removing the one you're passing.

https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/search?q=OnCreate&ref=cmdform

The wiki is here: https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked.  I had a look at the sample from https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher-examples.  Thanks again.. BTW is there any place to look for the API doc for neo4jclient.